# Fibonacci sequence on 68HC11 using 4-byte numbers

Tags: c, assembly, 68hc11

I'm trying to figure out a way to implement the Fibonacci sequence using a 68HC11 IDE that uses a Motorolla as11 assembler.

I've done it using 2-byte unsigned in little-endian format, now I'm attempting to change it using 4-byte variables, using big-endian

My pseudo-code (which is written in c):

```
RESULT = 1;
PREV = 1;
COUNT = N;
WHILE(COUNT > 2){
    NEXT = RESULT + PREV;
    PREV = RESULT;
    RESULT = NEXT;
    COUNT--;
}
```

I'll include some of my current assembly code. Please note that count is set to unsigned int at 1-byte, and prev, next, and result are unsigned ints at 2 bytes. N is unsigned, set to 10.

```
        ORG     $C000
        LDD     #1
        STD     RESULT      
        STD     PREV        
        LDAA    N
        STAA    COUNT       
WHILE   LDAA    COUNT
        CMPA    #2      
         BLS    ENDWHILE
         LDD    RESULT      
        ADDD    PREV    
         STD    NEXT           
         LDD    RESULT  
         STD    PREV           
         LDD    NEXT
         STD    RESULT         
         DEC    COUNT          
         BRA    WHILE       
ENDWHILE
DONE     BRA    DONE
    END
```

The issue that I'm having is now altering this (other than the obvious variable changes/declarations) N will begin at 40 now, not 10. Would altering my pseudo-code to include pointers allow me to implement it 1 to 1 better with big-endian? Since this is in little-endian, I assume I have to alter some of the branches. Yes this is an assignment for class, I'm not looking for the code, just some guidance would be nice.

Thank you!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comment_(computer_programming)

Answer (score 1):

(Your problem description is a bit vague as to what your actual problem is, so I may be guessing a bit.)

BTW, 68HC11 is big-endian.

The 68HC11 has a 16-bit accumulator, so as soon as your result overflows this, you need to do math operations in pieces.

I suppose you mean that by changing N from 10 to 40 your fibonacci number becomes too big to be stored in a 16-bit variable.

The use or not of pointers is irrelevant to your problem as you can solve it both with or without them.  For example, you can use a pointer to tell your routine where to store the result.

Depending on your maximum expected result, you need to adjust your routine.  I will assume you won't need to go over 32-bit result (N=47 => 2971215073).

Here's a partially tested but unoptimized possibility (using ASM11 assembler):

```
STACKTOP            equ       $1FF
RESET_VECTOR        equ       $FFFE

                    org       $100                ;RAM

result              rmb       4

                    org       $d000               ;ROM

;*******************************************************************************
; Purpose: Return the Nth fibonacci number in result
; Input  : HX -> 32-bit result
;        : A = Nth number to calculate
; Output : None
; Note(s):

GetFibonacci        proc
                    push                          ;macro to save D, X, Y

          ;--- define & initialize local variables

                    des:4                         ;allocate 4 bytes on stack
tmp@@               equ       5                   ;5,Y: temp number

                    ldab      #1
                    pshb
                    clrb
                    pshb:3
prev@@              equ       1                   ;1,Y: previous number (initialized to 1)

                    psha
n@@                 equ       0                   ;0,Y: N
          ;---
                    tsy                           ;Y -> local variables

                    clra
                    clrb
                    std       ,x
                    std       prev@@,y

                    ldd       #1
                    std       2,x
                    std       prev@@+2,y

Loop@@              ldaa      n@@,y
                    cmpa      #2
                    bls       Done@@

                    ldd       2,x
                    addd      prev@@+2,y
                    std       tmp@@+2,y

                    ldaa      1,x
                    adca      prev@@+1,y
                    staa      tmp@@+1,y

                    ldaa      ,x
                    adca      prev@@,y
                    staa      tmp@@,y

                    ldd       ,x
                    std       prev@@,y
                    ldd       2,x
                    std       prev@@+2,y

                    ldd       tmp@@,y
                    std       ,x
                    ldd       tmp@@+2,y
                    std       2,x

                    dec       n@@,y
                    bra       Loop@@

Done@@              ins:9                         ;de-allocate all locals from stack
                    pull                          ;macro to restore D, X, Y
                    rts

;*******************************************************************************
; Test code
;*******************************************************************************

Start               proc
                    ldx       #STACKTOP           ;setup our stack
                    txs

                    ldx       #result
                    ldaa      #40                 ;Nth fibonacci number to get
                    bsr       GetFibonacci
                    bra       *                   ;check 'result' for answer

                    org       RESET_VECTOR
                    dw        Start
```